# I need a noun in American English that represents the idiom 'to look on the bright side'

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

We're developing an application where we have categories users may progress towards, and one of them is 'to look on the bright side; to live without worry, etc.'. However, categories are titled with a single word, and I have failed to think of a word that perfectly suits that meaning.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: ... Pollyanna ...

Comment: I don't think people would aspire to be a Pollyanna, though. At least not where I'm from. ^_^

Comment: Forgot to say that we don't want to imply any bad meaning to the word

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An **optimist** is a person who looks on the bright side. Optimism is the word for the perspective itself.

**[Sanguinity](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sanguine)** is another option.

Added: Based on your criteria, I would go with either **carefreeness** or **lightheartedness**. I personally prefer the second and think it's used more often. Both words are commonly known, if that's what you mean by "popular."

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm wondering, since that category will be used in a magical girly game with fairies, if sanguinity would be suitable, since I don't find it playful and tricky. On the other side, the word has to be popular and well-known amongst American people.

Comment: If that's the context, I would not use sanguinity. It's a pretty advanced word. Optimist(ic) would be better.

Comment: well my concern is that 'optimistic' wouldn't stand for 'have no worries' and also 'to look on the funny side of things' maybe...

Comment: carefree, perhaps?

Comment: laid-back? easygoing?

Comment: hehe. after all that, i think given the context, Pollyanna may indeed be the way to go.

Comment: as far as I see Pollyanna implies some 'feet off the ground' meaning, which I'd like to avoid :) Please post 'carefreeness' as your answer, so that I accept it. Just one last question: does 'carefreeness' sound as something positive to a native American and is it widely popular? Thank you!

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: yes, I meant commonly-known. Thank you

Comment: lol. Almost gave you a minus for `Sanguinity`. That word is practically an antagonym (see definition 4 on your link), and is typically used in contexts where it is difficult to figure out which meaning was intended.

Answer (score 1):

How about *positivism* or *brightness* or *carefree*?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but onomatomaniak answered carefree first :))

Answer (score 1):

*[Cheerful](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cheerful)*, "noticeably happy and optimistic; bright and pleasant" may suit.

Also consider *[blithe](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blithe)*.  In one sense it means "happy, cheerful" (although Wiktionary claims this usage is dated or literary), and in another sense, "indifferent, careless, showing a lack of concern".  [Synonyms of it](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=blithe&send=Look+it+up) include 
*animated, buoyant, cheerful, gay, happy, jovial,  lighthearted, lively, merry, sprightly*.

While these are mostly adjectives rather than nouns, as category headings that might not matter.

Answer (score 0):

The common British name *Felicity* means "happiness" and would make a great category name.

Comment: OP isn't looking for a fairy name, so I changed it to match the question.